# I have written a function by the name of confirm but it does not work as i want

Tags: javascript

I want to show a text in confirm box but it does not show the text which I write.when the confirm box opened it show undifind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm()
{
    var x=confirm("the article will be deleted");
    if(x==true){
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're recursing infinitely. Your `confirm` function calls itself.

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error? Your braces aren't matched properly.

Comment: `function confirm()
{
var x=confirm("the article will be deleted");
if(x==true){
return true;
}
else
  {
return false;
  }
}`

Comment: You need to close the brace for the `if` before you write `else`.

Comment: Braces are not proper

Answer (score 4):

How about that if you want to use your own function, which does not make too much sense here:

your a-tag:

```
<a href="show_articles"><img src="newfolder/delete.jpg" onclick="return myConfirm();"></a>
```

your confirm-function:

```
function myConfirm() {
    return confirm("the article will be deleted");
}
```

Dont call your function `confirm`, because that's a predefined function in javascript.

Comment: I tryed but it does not work I mean it does not show "the article will be deleted" again.

Comment: how do you call that method? can you give some more information about that?

Comment: <a href="show_articles"><img src="newfolder/delete.jpg" onclick="return confirm();"></a>